# How can I make easy money?

Tags: metro-2033

Although I am playing on normal difficulty, I am almost always running low on money, and the ammo I find I have to spend on killing stuff.

I do and will *not* have the DLC Ranger Pack, and cheating is out of the question.

Is there a way to get rich more easily?

Comment: Any reason on the downvote? I could improve on my question, if you tell me where or how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exploit, not a glitch or anything.
Ranger pack DLC is REQUIRED.

> First off, when fighting the first
>  bandits with Bourbon, next to their
>  Campfire you will find a bunch of ammo
>  and more importantly a Volt Driver.
>  Pick up this volt driver now. When you
>  get to the Market, sell it for either
>  the Auto Shotty or the Thar with
>  Scope.Either works. Now, continue
>  playing until you find yourself in
>  Andrew the Blacksmith's room. On his
>  bed will be a Volt Driver, the Heavy
>  Auto Shotty and some Shotgun ammo.
>  Ignore these and go to the weapon
>  stall in the middle of the merchants.
>  Sell the Thar/Shotty for a DOUBLE
>  BARREL Shotgun. Then return to
>  Andrew's bed, pick up the Heavy
>  shotgun or the volt driver, whichever
>  you don't want, and return to the
>  merchant. Sell this weapon for ANOTHER
>  Double Barrel shotgun. Now, you can
>  either keep the remaining weapon for
>  your own personal use, or sell it for
>  yet ANOTHER Double Barrel shotgun. If
>  you do the latter, you can soon swap
>  out the double barrel for an
>  Automatic+Bayonet Shotgun in the Front
>  Lines. it's down a flight of stairs
>  near the Wounded tent behind Communist
>  front lines, on top of a pipe beside a
>  corpse. Now, continue through with
>  this until you are inside the station
>  past the Defense chapter. Up a flight
>  of stairs just on the inside of the
>  first radiation hotzone, to the left,
>  is a dead body with a Helsing, pick
>  that up and sell it once you've
>  delivered Sasha to safety, for another
>  Automatic Shotgun w/ Bayonet. Continue
>  playing until you reach the Black
>  Station, now. Inside of a bus near a
>  Patrol (somewhere close to the
>  Generator) you will find a Helsing.
>  Pick that up and keep it until you
>  reach Polis, where you can yet again
>  sell it for an Automatic Shotgun w/
>  Bayonet. Once through with the Library
>  you can pick a Volt Driver or Heavy
>  Automatic shotgun to actually play
>  with through the rest of the campaign,
>  as Polis was the last station with an
>  available trader and Ammo exchange
>  Kiosk. This little trick makes using
>  Ranger Hardcore mode unbelievably fun,
>  as you no longer run out of ammo
>  entirely, though still feel like its
>  rare.

[Source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/935091-metro-2033/56560232)

Comment: I do not have the Ranger pack, and am not planning to buy it. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Are you OK with cheats, then?

Comment: Sorry that you couldn't get a better answer. :-(